# Exit function doesn't work in OpenCV with python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I just want to capture one frame, save it to `test.png` and then exit the code.
In this program `exit()` doesn't work, I have to use CTRL+C from the terminal every time.

```
import cv2

#cv2.namedWindow("window")
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

if cap.isOpened(): # if we are able to capture the first frame.
    val, frame = cap.read()
else:
    val = False
while val:
    #cv2.imshow("window", frame)
    cv2.imwrite('test.png',frame)
    val, frame = cap.read()
    key = cv2.waitKey(20)
    if key == 27: # exit on ESC
        break

cap.release
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
exit()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you sure that the break is reached?

Comment: I don't think so, ESC doesn't work. @Vanojx1

Comment: try puttin a print statement on the key variable before your if statement, this way you will find if the break is reached (which is not). You can update you question then.

Comment: @Bouramas, it keeps on printing the number 255.

Comment: Thus you see the issue @amolkulkarni . Thats why the break statement is not reached.

Comment: Btw: if you want to capture one frame, why do you use while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv::waitKey` only works if any openCV window is present and maybe active.

Since you commented `#cv2.namedWindow("window")` and `#cv2.imshow("window", frame)` out there is no waitKey time and no chance to fetch the key.

Does it work if you activate namedWindow and imshow?

To be sure additionally try

```
if key > 0: # exit on ESC
    break
```

to cancel on ANY keypress (but you still need an active openCV window)

To capture a single frame try this:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

val = False
maxTry = 100 # maximum number of tries to capture a frame from an opened device
cTry = 0

if cap.isOpened(): # if we are able to capture the first        frame.
    while (!val) and (cTry < maxTry)
        val, frame = cap.read()
        cTry = cTry + 1
else:
    val = False
if val:
    cv2.imwrite('test.png',frame)
else:
    print "No image captured"

cap.release
exit()
```

I am not a python programmer so please forgive me any syntax errors (and give me a hint to correct them)

Comment: That's basically what I suggested and apparently it still doesn't work.

Comment: it works when I remove the comment #. But as i have mentioned in the question, i want it to capture one frame and exit.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding & 0xFF to the wait key:

```
key = cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF
```

You also need an active window:

> Note
>   The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.

Comment: Does any other key work? Instead of comparing with 27 try: ord('q')

Comment: Do one more test. Show image with cvw.imshow. Maybe the window capture the keystrokes.

Comment: Nothing. Still the same

Comment: Note

 

The function only works if there is at least one HighGUI window created and the window is active. If there are several HighGUI windows, any of them can be active.

Comment: This is a really good reason that opencv should provide a way to make a window active programmatically!

Answer (score 0):

The method waitkey(t) waits t in milliseconds, so your code is waiting 20 ms for a key press for each loop. Considering that your

```
cv2.imwrite('test.png',frame)
```

might take some time to write to file, are you perhaps pressing your exiting key at the wrong moment?